# How to get a number in my result set

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model setup and and am performing a SQL query with some grouping and distinct counts.  However sequelize is returning these counts as Strings. How can I return this as numbers, or am I going to have to manually cast my result set?

```
 report_table.findAll({
        attributes: [
            [report_table.sequelize.fn("concat", report_table.sequelize.col("application"), report_table.sequelize.col("document_title")), "_id"],
            "application", "document_title",  [report_table.sequelize.fn('count', report_table.sequelize.col('view_id')), "view count"],
            [report_table.sequelize.fn('count', report_table.sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', report_table.sequelize.col('client_id'))), "user count"],
            [report_table.sequelize.fn('max', report_table.sequelize.col('date')), "last view"]
        ],
        where: {
            tag_type: "event",
            application: {
                $in: applications
            }
        },
        group: ["application", "document_title"],
        order: [
            [report_table.sequelize.fn('count', report_table.sequelize.col('view_id')), "DESC"]
        ]
    }).then(callback);
```